# List of Django exceptions and response codes

Tags: python, django, exception, http-status-codes

Certain django exceptions have associated status codes.  For example:

- The `SuspiciousOperation` exception returns a **400** if it is raised.
- The `PermissionDenied` exception returns a **403** if it is raised.
- The `Http404` exception returns a **404** status if it is raised.

Where can I find a comprehensive list of this?  It is lacking on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/

Comment: I guess this can be a elaborated into a [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com) for improving the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the exception handlers: https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/core/handlers/base.py#L139. As you can see there are only 3 "named" exceptions catched there (I'm not counting `SystemExit`), everything else is handled by [handle_uncaught_exception](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/core/handlers/base.py#L214) and results in the 500 error.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the only two. Everything else, if it's not caught, is a 500 status, which is the catch-all "server error" code.

Comment: +1 Though would be good to add some details on how do you know that: based on the experience, or from reading the documentation, or the source code..Thanks.

Comment: Not true.  SuspiciousOperation results in a 400.  I'll add that to my list